# fetch datas from two tables and differentiate between them

Tags: mysql

I have two tables and want displays rows from the two one in the same page ordered by date created.

Here my query:

```
SELECT  R.*, R.id as id_return
FROM    return R
UNION
ALL
SELECT  A.*, A.id as id_buy
FROM    buy A
WHERE
R.id_buyer = '$user' AND R.id_buyer = A.id_buyer AND (R.stats='1' OR R.stats='3') OR A.stats='4'
ORDER
BY R.date, A.date DESC LIMIT $from , 20
```

With this query i get this error message:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ...
```

And here how i think i can differentiate between the results: (Knowing if the result is from the table `RETURN` or from the table `BUY`)

```
if(isset($hist_rows["id_return"])) {
   // show RETURN rows
} else {
   // show BUY rows
}
```

Please what is wrong with the query, and if the method to differentiate between tables are correct ?

**EDIT**

***Here my tables sample:***

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `return` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_buyer` INT(12) NOT NULL,
`id_seller` INT(12) NOT NULL,
`message` TEXT NOT NULL,
`stats` INT(1) NOT NULL,
`date` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`update`  varchar(30)
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `buy` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_buyer` INT(12) NOT NULL,
`product` INT(12) NOT NULL,
`title` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
`stats` INT(1) NOT NULL,
`date` varchar(30) NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Comment: Post you table return and buy schema

Comment: I don't think a `union all` makes sense for your problem.  You should edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: since `union all` require same structure, in my case it's wrong to use it like this ... i am looking for a way to display the results from the two tables in same page ordered by date created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure the two table  `return`  and  `buy`  have the same number  (and type sequence) of colummns .. if not  the query fails

try select only the column you need from both the table   and be sure that these are in correspondenting number and type

```
SELECT  R.col1, R.col2, R.id as id_return
FROM    return R
UNION ALL
SELECT  A.col1, A.col2,  A.id as id_buy
FROM    buy A
WHERE
........
```

Looking to your code you should select the same number and type of column form boith the table eg de sample below: 
(where i have added the different column and selecting null from the table where are not present)
I have aslore referred the proper where condition to each table ..

```
SELECT  
     R.'from return' as `source_table`
   , R.`id` 
   , R.`id_buyer` 
   , null as product
   , null as title
   , R.`id_seller` as id_seller
   , R-`message` 
   , R.`stats` 
   , R.`date` 
   , R.`update`
FROM    return R
WHERE R.id_buyer = '$user'
AND (R.stats='1' OR R.stats='3')
UNION ALL 
SELECT  
     A.'from buy'
   , A.`id` 
   , A.`id_buyer` 
   , A.`product` 
   , A.`title` 
   , null 
   , null
   , A.`stats` 
   , A.`date` 
   , null
FROM    buy A
WHERE 
A.id_buyer = '$user'
AND A.stats='4'
ORDER BY `source table`, date DESC LIMIT $from , 20
```

for retrive te value of the first column you should use in your case

```
echo  $hist_rows["source_table"];
```

Otherwise i the two table are in some way related you should look at a join (left join) for link the two table and select the the repated column
(but this is another question)

But if you need left join you can try

```
SELECT  
    R.`id` 
   , R.`id_buyer` 
   , R.`id_seller` as id_seller
   , R-`message` 
   , R.`stats` 
   , R.`date` 
   , R.`update`
   , A.`id` 
   , A.`id_buyer` 
   , A.`product` 
   , A.`title` 
   , null 
   , null
   , A.`stats` 
   , A.`date` 
FROM    return  R
LEFT JOIN buy A ON  R.id_buyer = A.id_buyer 
AND  R.id_buyer = '$user' 
AND (R.stats='1' OR R.stats='3')
AND A.stats='4'
ORDER BY R.date DESC LIMIT $from , 20
```

Comment: The structure of the two tables are not same.

Comment: Then the select with union fails .. in this case if you need a single select with common column you can select explicitally only the columns you need .. otherwise you must perform two distinct select ..

Comment: I want make one query to display results from the two tables.

Comment: If you spell out the column names (not with a `.*` with an alias) this works

Comment: @BraveType  the you must  select explicitally the column form both the table see the sample in updated answer ..like Drew propose in his comment

Comment: @Drew   . correct  .. this is what i'm try  suggest to the OP

Comment: yeah I mean that for the op, I know you know this and you said it I think in your first rev

Comment: I just tried what you are suggesting but i got the same error :(

Comment: Then try perform the new query in a mysql ide .. and be sure you don't have other errors .. (be sure that  the columns in select are in the same number and in corresponding type)

Comment: Yes i did that all are correct but i get the same error ... i think to use `UNION ALL` you must have the same table schema. I tried with `JOIN` ...  i din't got the errors but i don't get the results i am waiting for ... showing the results from the two tables ordered by date created and with different rows.

Comment: @scaisEdge i just tried it, but i get only table `return` rows, `buy` table return nothing and when i use the columns of `buy` table i get error messages. But we escaped last day error ... good progress thank you so much :)

Comment: @scaisEdge I get this error for all columns of second `SELECT`: `Notice: Undefined index: product in ...`

Comment: If you are using a select union you have only one select .... i don't understand ... or you have splitted the query in two ?

Comment: @scaisEdge i used the same code you given me, but columns of second `select` not work !

Comment: If you use the query provided then the column name are always the name of the first table  so the index fo accessing to the column value are always the column of the first  select  ... for trial try perform a select union in a sqlide and you see that the column header is always the column header of the firts select ..

Comment: @scaisEdge but i want show rows of the two tables and not only the first table ... my question was for that ... i don't need `union` if i want it only for one table :) and `JOIN` will solve my problem in that case ... i need showing the result of the two one at time :) thank's.

Comment: @BraveType  . i have update the asnwer with  a join  query

Comment: @scaisEdge i already made my query with LEFT JOIN but i have two problems with that query: 1- I have duplicated rows, 2- How to differentiate between the two tables when i show the rows (Because rows of first table not like the second one, and the HTML structure not same too). You can check here my another post about this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39557078/how-to-detect-rows-come-from-what-table-when-using-join?noredirect=1, Thank yuo so much for your support.

Comment: @BraveType   .looking to question in your comment  ..I  think you really need a union and for this you can know if the row is from one table or from another by the value of the first column  .. (alias source table)  .. i have slightly update the query with union . in my answer

Comment: @scaisEdge how to call the value of the first table ? thank's

Comment: If you use the select union you obtain  a single set of rows  mixed with firts and second  (sub) select .. if you need first one set of rows and the other for second you can use order by  .. i have update the answer adding an order by on table ..

Comment: @scaisEdge you can give example on how to show the first column please ?

Comment: @BraveType  . i have name the first column `source_table`  and have update the answer adding  a simple echo for the column  ... hope is what you are  looking for ..

Comment: @scaisEdge it's what i am looking for right ! thank you so much for your answer and time, i've learned many from you. i mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `union all`, the queries need to have *exactly* the same columns in the same order.  If the types are not quite the same, then they are converted to the same type.

So, you don't want `union all`.  I'm guessing you want a `join`.  Something like this:

```
SELECT r.co1, r.col2, . . ., r.id as id_return,
       b.col1, b.col2, . . ., b.id as id_buy
FROM return r JOIN
     buy b
     ON r.id_buyer = b.id_buyer
WHERE r.id_buyer = '$user' and
      (r.stats in (1, 3) OR A.stats = 4)
ORDER BY R.date, A.date DESC
LIMIT $from, 20;
```

This query is only a guess as to what you might want.

Comment: return is also a reserved word (R)

Comment: this query return a duplicated results from table `RETURN` only and nothing from `BUY` table.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a union, select a string that you set identifying each query:

```
SELECT  'R', R.*, R.id as id_return
FROM    return R
UNION
ALL
SELECT  'A', A.*, A.id as id_buy
```

This way your string 'R' or 'A' is the first column, showing you where it came from. We can't really know why it's failing without the full query, but I'd guess your $from might be empty?

As for your

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ...
```

Run the query directly first to get the sql sorted out before putting it into your PHP script.  The boolean false indicates the query failed.