# How to detect rows come from what table when using JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I have this mysql query:

```
SELECT  R.*, A.*

    FROM             buy A
    JOIN             return R
    ON               A.id_buyer = R.id_buyer 
    WHERE            A.id_acheter = '$id' and R.stats in (5, 4) and A.stats in (14, 15) 
    ORDER BY R.id, A.id
```

First of all when i use this query i get a duplicated rows ... i used GROUP BY in order to solve the problem but nothing done yet.

And here sample datas:

***BUY Table:***

```
> +-------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
> |id           |  id_buyer     | product   | title       | stats       |
> +-------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
> |1            | 12            | Amazon    | Shoes       | 4           |
> +-------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
> |2            | 12            | Amazon    | Glasses     | 5           |
> +-------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
> |3            | 16            | Ebay      | Glasses     | 2           |
> +-------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

***RETURN Table:***

```
> +-------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
> |id           |  id_buyer     | Message   | Date        | stats       |
> +-------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
> |1            | 12            | Hi        | 02/05/16    | 14          |
> +-------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
> |2            | 12            | What?     | 02/05/16    | 0           |
> +-------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
> |3            | 12            | Yes       | 02/05/16    | 15          |
> +-------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

**Desired results:**

Since i have not the same columns on the tables, i don't know how i can manage my PHP code to show this result ?

```
> +-------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
> |1            | 12            | Hi        | 02/05/16    | 14          |
> +-------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+

> +-------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
> |3            | 12            | Yes       | 02/05/16    | 15          |
> +-------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+

> +-------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
> |1            | 12            | Amazon    | Shoes       | 4           |
> +-------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+

> +-------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
> |2            | 12            | Amazon    | Glasses     | 5           |
> +-------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

***Here what i have done but with no success:***

```
<table>
<?php
$id = "12";
$req = $mysqli->query("SELECT  R.*, A.*, R.id as id_reservation, A.id as id_buy

    FROM             buy A
    JOIN             return R
    ON               A.id_buyer = R.id_buyer 
    WHERE            A.id_acheter = '$id' and R.stats in (5, 4) and A.stats in (14, 15) 
    ORDER BY R.id, A.id");

While($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($req)) {

$id_buyer = $rows["id_buyer"];
if(isset($rows["id_reservation"])) {
$id = $rows["id_reservation"];
$result1 = $rows["product"];
$result2 = $rows["title"];
} else {
$id = $rows["id_buy"];
$result1 = $rows["message"];
$result2 = $rows["date"];
}
$stats = $rows["stats"];
?>
<tr>
<td><?=$id?></td>
<td><?=$id_buyer?></td>
<td><?=$result1?></td>
<td><?=$result2?></td>
<td><?=$stats?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

***EDIT (UNION approch):***

```
SELECT  
     R.'from return'
   , R.`id` 
   , R.`id_buyer` 
   , null as product
   , null as title
   , R.`id_seller` as id_seller
   , R-`message` 
   , R.`stats` 
   , R.`date` 
   , R.`update`
FROM    return R
WHERE R.id_buyer = '$user'
AND (R.stats='1' OR R.stats='3')
UNION ALL 

SELECT  
     A.'from buy'
   , A.`id` 
   , A.`id_buyer` 
   , A.`product` 
   , A.`title` 
   , null 
   , null
   , A.`stats` 
   , A.`date` 
   , null
FROM    buy A
WHERE 
A.id_buyer = '$user'
AND A.stats='4'
ORDER BY R.date DESC LIMIT $from , 20
```

Here we have the `UNION` approch, but only columns of first `SELECT` that works, the second `SELECT`'s columns not work.

I still get this error for second select columns only: `Notice: Undefined index: product in ...`

Comment: Try left join instead of inner join

Comment: @chenchuk i just tried it, i have exactly the same problem nothing changed :) thank's for the suggestion.

Comment: Your desired result seems to consist of two different result sets from two different tables. You should probably do two separate queries.

Comment: @jeroen yes i want that but with performing only one query ... since i need to put a pagination system in the same page and show them together.

Comment: I fail to see any logic here, but you could always try a `UNION`...

Comment: @jeroen I tried `union` but i get columns of the first select only.

Comment: You don't need one query to do to pagination, 2 queries are just a little more complicated. And if `union` doesn't work, post your `union` code so we can fix it, `union` (and some casting) is what you need here, if you are sure you want to get this resultset.

Comment: @Solarflare i just modified the post and added my `UNION` approch.

Comment: *"i used `GROUP BY` in order to solve the problem"* -- `GROUP BY` cannot solve the "problem" of duplicate rows because this is not what `GROUP BY` does for a living. [`DISTINCT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) is in charge with removing the duplicates.

Comment: I used `DISTINCT` but got same results :( really annoying  problem

Comment: @BraveType I am actually still not sure what you are trying to do with your `union`-code, but it does not work. Change `R-\`message\`` to `R.\`message\`` and  `R.'from return'` to `'from return` as src_table` and  `A.'from buy'` to `'from buy'`. The column `src_table` now tells you what table you got your result from. `Limit` will only work for your second table (if you want 20 rows in total, use another subquery around it `select * from (select ... from ... union all select ...) as x limit 20`)